# Publishing to npm with Travis CI

Tags: node.js, npm, travis-ci

How do I publish to npm using Travis CI? I've tried the following .travis.yml:

```
language: nodejs
node_js:
- '6'
- '6.1'
- '5.11'
before_script:
- npm install -g nodeunit
script: nodeunit
deploy:
  provider: npm
  email: my_email
  api_key: "encrypted"
```

But when it comes to the npm bit , I get:

```
npm ERR! publish Failed PUT 400
npm ERR! Error: Not found : package-name
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

With

```
api_key:
   secure: "..."
```

I get another error:

```
NPM API key format changed recently. If your deployment fails, check your
API key in ~/.npmrc.
http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/npm/
~/.npmrc size: 53
env: <this is my unencrypted api key>: No such file or directory
```

**SOLUTION**

Finally solved it. The npm version on travis was really old (1.4.28). All I had to do was to put a :

```
before_script:
- npm install -g npm@'>=3'
```

And now it works!

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things that might be going wrong. First, have you checked your `package.json` and made sure there is a `name` property? Or does the name conflict with an existing npm package? The error message suggests that there is something wrong there.

But there is another problem. Your API key appears to be the string literal `"encrypted"`, unless you are just using that as a placeholder for this example. It should look something like this:

```
provider: npm
email: my.email@gmail.com
api_key:
  secure: "Esiel6Dws/vjwNshQ/nmx43+7/lpqsl8Dkd ..."
skip_cleanup: true
```

Also note the `skip_cleanup` property. If you want to publish any artifacts of your build, you should include this.

The encryption can be done with the [Travis CLI](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb). See the [`encrypt`](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb#encrypt) and [`setup`](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb#setup) commands.

For a working example, see my [`.travis.yml`](https://github.com/akim-mcmath/deep-map/blob/e825ebdb87cef370dab8348c3985902eab86bf4b/.travis.yml) file on [this](https://github.com/akim-mcmath/deep-map) project on GitHub.

Finally, make sure your API key is correct. On the computer on which you are logged in to npm, check your `~/.npmrc` file.

```
nano ~/.npmrc
```

Then find the line that starts with `//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=`. Make sure that you use this token as your API key in `.travis.yml`. The token will be valid for as long as you are logged in to npm on that computer.

Comment: the package is already published manually, i'm just  trying to update it automatically with travis. Also, the key and email are right, I just placeholdered them heh. Should try adding the secure, see what happens

Comment: Instead of manually adding `secure`, I would suggest just encrypting your key with the Travis CLI, which will do it for you. `travis encrypt $API_KEY --add deploy.api_key`

Comment: And another possibility is that there is a version conflict. Is the version in your `package.json` possibly already published?

Comment: it was added by travis encrypt , but i tried removing it to see if it works. and no, there is no conflict. versions are neat

Comment: updated my answer with what i get with api_key: secure: "blabla"

Comment: OK, I can only keep guessing, but I think we're getting somewhere. Did you check your `~/.npmrc` and make sure the API key you are using matches the one on the line starting with `//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=`?

Comment: not sure how i can check the ~/.npmrc of a docker container on travis tho. don't think that's it anyways

Comment: It's your `npmrc` on the computer you are using, not on Travis. When you login to npm, it will put an authorization token into your local `npmrc`, which will be valid until you log out. That's what you use for your API key.

Comment: i've got the api key directly from npm. my local npmrc has nothing to do with what travis uses to publish the packege

Comment: When you say directly from npm, do you mean from `https://www.npmjs.com/settings/tokens`? If so, these are the same tokens as you will find in your `npmrc`. If not, then where did you get the token from?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116019/discussion-between-mcmath-and-overburn).

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have solved, but I want share my working solution:

First I have generated a npm-token following [these instruction](https://www.npmjs.com/settings/tokens).
Briefly I have done the login to npm with `npm login` on my pc and then get it with `cat ~/.npmrc` to get it.

Then I have added an enviroment var to travis:

[image: npm env token]

Finally I have added to `.travis.yml`:

```
deploy:
  provider: npm
  email: my-email@provider.com
  api_key: $NPM_TOKEN
  on:
    tags: true
```

Which will publish to npm repository only when the build is successfully and when any tag are added to the git repository (so you could publish only when you need it).